# Solving Bernoulli equation transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

I'm trying to solve the Bernoulli's equation via perturbation method but I need some help understanding how its done:

We start off with $y'=-y+\epsilon y^2$ with $y(0)=1$.

Then how is it possible to get the transformation $y_{ex}= e^{-t}/1+\epsilon(e^{-t}-1)$ and then change it to $y'=-y$ and $y(0)=1$ and solve it from there?

And how are you supposed to even come up with the $y_{ex}$ out of the blue?

Comment: is this not a logistic equation?

Answer (score 1):

Or treat it as a Bernoulli ODE by setting $y=u^{-1}$ and 
$$
-u'=-u+ϵ \implies (u(t)-ϵ)=e^{t}·(u(0)-ϵ)\\[0.7em]
 \implies y(t)=\frac{y(0)}{ϵ·y(0)+e^t·(1-ϵ·y(0))}=\frac{e^{-t}·y(0)}{1+ϵ·(e^{-t}-1)·y(0)}
$$

---

However, from the task description you are to use this as an example for the perturbation method, so setting $y=y_0+ϵ·y_1+ϵ^2·y_2+…$ one gets
$$
y'_0+ϵ·y'_1+ϵ^2·y'_2+…=-(y_0+ϵ·y_1+ϵ^2·y_2+…)+ϵ·(y_0+ϵ·y_1+ϵ^2·y_2+…)^2
$$
and by comparing the terms of equal power of $ϵ$ one successively obtains equations
\begin{align}
y'_0&=-y_0\\
y'_1&=-y_1+y_0^2\\
y'_2&=-y_2+2y_0y_1\\
y'_3&=-y_3+y_1^2+2y_0y_2\\
&…
\end{align}
which all have the homogeneous solution $e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = -y + \epsilon y^2 \implies \frac{dy}{\epsilon y^2 - y} = dt$$
Using partial fractions:
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon y^2 - y} = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon y - 1} - \frac{1}{y}$$
From this, we have: 
$$\ln(\epsilon y - 1) - \ln(y) = t + C$$
$$\ln\bigg(\frac{\epsilon y - 1}{y}\bigg) = \cdot t+ C$$
$$y^{-1} = \epsilon - A\cdot e^t$$

Comment: Oh, wow.. oops. Making an edit. Thanks @LutzL